# How to call Python method from C# using IronPython

Tags: c#, ironpython, method-call

I have a Python method that is taking some arguments and returns a value. I am trying to call it from my C# code using IronPython.

The Python method is like:

```
def encrypt(K,CHARS,param):
    L = len(param)
    e = pyffx.String(K, alphabet=CHARS, length=L)
    return e.encrypt(param)
```

---

//C#

```
var options = new Dictionary<string, object> { ["Debug"] = true };
                options["Frames"] = true;
                options["FullFrames"] = false;

                ScriptRuntime ipy = Python.CreateRuntime(options);
                ScriptEngine engine = ipy.GetEngine("py");

                var paths = engine.GetSearchPaths();
                paths.Add(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib");
                paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib");
                paths.Add(@"C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages");
                engine.SetSearchPaths(paths);

                dynamic pythonscript = ipy.UseFile("encryptclient.py");

                string s= pythonscript.encrypt("abc", "xyz", "");
```

I am not familiar with Python. Could some guide me what is the way I should be passing parameters or call this python method.